# How do you get user choices from a Pymel LayoutDialog?

Tags: user-interface, maya, pymel

The following code is taken from the Pymel docs here: https://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2020/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/PyMel/generated/functions/pymel.core.windows/pymel.core.windows.layoutDialog.html

Although the example is called `checkboxPrompt` it doesn't show how the state of the checkbox can be retrieved. The `pm.layoutDialog` function only returns the choice of button used to dismiss the dialog. The MEL and Maya.cmds docs for the same command don't explain this either. So how is it done?

```py
 
import pymel.core as pm

def checkboxPrompt():
    # Get the dialog's formLayout.
    #
    form = pm.setParent(q=True)

    # layoutDialog's are not resizable, so hard code a size here,
    # to make sure all UI elements are visible.
    #
    pm.formLayout(form, e=True, width=300)

    t = pm.text(l='What do you want to do?')

    b1 = pm.button(l='Abort', c='pm.layoutDialog( dismiss="Abort" )' )
    b2 = pm.button(l='Skip', c='pm.layoutDialog( dismiss="Skip" )' )
    b3 = pm.button(l='Continue', c='pm.layoutDialog( dismiss="Continue" )' )

    cb1 = pm.checkBox(label='Remember my choice')

    spacer = 5
    top = 5
    edge = 5

    pm.formLayout(form, edit=True,
                  attachForm=[(t, 'top', top), (t, 'left', edge), (t, 'right', edge), (b1, 'left', edge), (b3, 'right', edge), (cb1, 'left', edge), (cb1, 'bottom', spacer)],
                  attachNone=[(t, 'bottom'), (b1, 'bottom'), (b2, 'bottom'), (b3, 'bottom'), (cb1, 'right')],
                  attachControl=[(b1, 'top', spacer, t), (b2, 'top', spacer, t), (b3, 'top', spacer, t), (cb1, 'top', spacer, b1)],
                  attachPosition=[(b1, 'right', spacer, 33), (b2, 'left', spacer, 33), (b2, 'right', spacer, 66), (b3, 'left', spacer, 66)])

print pm.layoutDialog(ui=checkboxPrompt)
```

Answer (score 1):

Lot of the time the documentation skip lot of elements to maintain a certain simplicity but because of this we often find ourselves without the solution and/or with very basic examples.

In your case, there is multiple way to get the checkbox value, you can for example:

- Add a `callback` on the checkbox with parameters `changeCommand` or `onCommand / offCommand` to update a python `global` variable you created earlier on your code.
- A simpler way is to set `lambda` functions to the `command` parameter (instead of a string) to retrieve the checkbox value and set the proper `dismiss` value.

**Here is the code for the second methods I talk above:**

```py
import pymel.core as pm

def checkboxPrompt():
    # Get the dialog's formLayout.
    form = pm.setParent(q=True)
    
    # Function method to query the value of the checkbox
    def getRememberMyChoice(checkbox_id):
        if pm.checkBox(checkbox_id, query=True, value=True):
            return ':Yes'
        return ':No'

    # layoutDialog's are not resizable, so hard code a size here,
    # to make sure all UI elements are visible.
    pm.formLayout(form, e=True, width=300)

    t = pm.text(l='What do you want to do?')

    b1 = pm.button(l='Abort', c=lambda *args: pm.layoutDialog( dismiss="Abort"+getRememberMyChoice(checkbox1) ) )
    b2 = pm.button(l='Skip', c=lambda *args: pm.layoutDialog( dismiss="Skip"+getRememberMyChoice(checkbox1) ) )
    b3 = pm.button(l='Continue', c=lambda *args: pm.layoutDialog( dismiss="Continue"+getRememberMyChoice(checkbox1) ) )
 
    checkbox1 = pm.checkBox(label='Remember my choice')

    spacer = 5
    top = 5
    edge = 5

    pm.formLayout(form, edit=True,
                  attachForm=[(t, 'top', top), (t, 'left', edge), (t, 'right', edge), (b1, 'left', edge), (b3, 'right', edge), (checkbox1, 'left', edge), (checkbox1, 'bottom', spacer)],
                  attachNone=[(t, 'bottom'), (b1, 'bottom'), (b2, 'bottom'), (b3, 'bottom'), (checkbox1, 'right')],
                  attachControl=[(b1, 'top', spacer, t), (b2, 'top', spacer, t), (b3, 'top', spacer, t), (checkbox1, 'top', spacer, b1)],
                  attachPosition=[(b1, 'right', spacer, 33), (b2, 'left', spacer, 33), (b2, 'right', spacer, 66), (b3, 'left', spacer, 66)])

print (pm.layoutDialog(ui=checkboxPrompt))
```

Executing the code, (check or not the checkbox) then closing by clicking one of the button will print you this:

```py
# First word ("Continue") depends on the button you clicked
# Yes or No (after the ":") is the state of the "Remember my choice" checkbox 
Continue:Yes
```